# Scala: how to merge a collection of Maps

Tags: scala, dictionary, folding, scala-collections

I have a List of Map[String, Double], and I'd like to merge their contents into a single Map[String, Double].  How should I do this in an idiomatic way?  I imagine that I should be able to do this with a fold.  Something like:

```
val newMap = Map[String, Double]() /: listOfMaps { (accumulator, m) => ... }
```

Furthermore, I'd like to handle key collisions in a generic way.  That is, if I add a key to the map that already exists, I should be able to specify a function that returns a Double (in this case) and takes the existing value for that key, plus the value I'm trying to add.  If the key does not yet exist in the map, then just add it and its value unaltered.

In my specific case I'd like to build a single Map[String, Double] such that if the map already contains a key, then the Double will be added to the existing map value.

I'm working with mutable maps in my specific code, but I'm interested in more generic solutions, if possible.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

How about this one:

```
def mergeMap[A, B](ms: List[Map[A, B]])(f: (B, B) => B): Map[A, B] =
  (Map[A, B]() /: (for (m <- ms; kv <- m) yield kv)) { (a, kv) =>
    a + (if (a.contains(kv._1)) kv._1 -> f(a(kv._1), kv._2) else kv)
  }

val ms = List(Map("hello" -> 1.1, "world" -> 2.2), Map("goodbye" -> 3.3, "hello" -> 4.4))
val mm = mergeMap(ms)((v1, v2) => v1 + v2)

println(mm) // prints Map(hello -> 5.5, world -> 2.2, goodbye -> 3.3)
```

And it works in both 2.7.5 and 2.8.0.

Comment: This is exactly how I was trying to do it initially.  I didn't think to place the for-comprehension there -- I'm still getting used to using them like this, but it makes sense.  In this case I can see how it's much like Python's list comprehensions, which I'm far more comfortable with.  Also like the use of the result-bearing if expression inside the call to a.+().

Comment: Thank you very much!, I made a little change, Instead of receiving a `List[Map[A,B]]` I change it for `Seq[Map[A,B]]` so its more generic and you can avoid calling `ms.toList` when, for example `ms` is an `ArrayBuffer`, as in my case.

Answer (score 48):

Well, you could do:

```
mapList reduce (_ ++ _)
```

except for the special requirement for collision.

Since you do have that special requirement, perhaps the best would be doing something like this (2.8):

```
def combine(m1: Map, m2: Map): Map = {
  val k1 = Set(m1.keysIterator.toList: _*)
  val k2 = Set(m2.keysIterator.toList: _*)
  val intersection = k1 & k2

  val r1 = for(key <- intersection) yield (key -> (m1(key) + m2(key)))
  val r2 = m1.filterKeys(!intersection.contains(_)) ++ m2.filterKeys(!intersection.contains(_)) 
  r2 ++ r1
}
```

You can then add this method to the map class through the Pimp My Library pattern, and use it in the original example instead of "`++`":

```
class CombiningMap(m1: Map[Symbol, Double]) {
  def combine(m2: Map[Symbol, Double]) = {
    val k1 = Set(m1.keysIterator.toList: _*)
    val k2 = Set(m2.keysIterator.toList: _*)
    val intersection = k1 & k2
    val r1 = for(key <- intersection) yield (key -> (m1(key) + m2(key)))
    val r2 = m1.filterKeys(!intersection.contains(_)) ++ m2.filterKeys(!intersection.contains(_))
    r2 ++ r1
  }
}

// Then use this:
implicit def toCombining(m: Map[Symbol, Double]) = new CombiningMap(m)

// And finish with:
mapList reduce (_ combine _)
```

While this was written in 2.8, so `keysIterator` becomes `keys` for 2.7, `filterKeys` might need to be written in terms of `filter` and `map`, `&` becomes `**`, and so on, it shouldn't be too different.

Comment: With modern Scala: val k1 = m1.keysIterator.toSet

Answer (score 26):

I'm surprised no one's come up with this solution yet:

```
myListOfMaps.flatten.toMap
```

Does exactly what you need:

1. Merges the list to a single Map
2. Weeds out any duplicate keys

Example:

```
scala> List(Map('a -> 1), Map('b -> 2), Map('c -> 3), Map('a -> 4, 'b -> 5)).flatten.toMap
res7: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Symbol,Int] = Map('a -> 4, 'b -> 5, 'c -> 3)
```

`flatten` turns the list of maps into a flat list of tuples, `toMap` turns the list of tuples into a map with all the duplicate keys removed

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, but doesn't sum values for duplicate keys as the OP requires.

Comment: Or you can use flatMap

Comment: @wbmrcb How would you use flatMap in this case? With flatMap, the flattening occurs *after* the mapping, but it's the inverse here. So how would it work?

Comment: @electric-Coffee if each of the the Maps contain multiple key-value pairs, this takes ONLY the last Map

Answer (score 6):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, another solution which **handles duplicate keys** and is only **based on the standard library** consists in merging the `Map`s as sequences (`flatten`) before applying the new [groupMapReduce](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#groupMapReduce[K,B](key:A=%3EK)(f:A=%3EB)(reduce:(B,B)=%3EB):scala.collection.immutable.Map[K,B]) operator which (as its name suggests) is an equivalent of a `groupBy` followed by a mapping and a reduce step of grouped values:

```
List(Map("hello" -> 1.1, "world" -> 2.2), Map("goodbye" -> 3.3, "hello" -> 4.4))
  .flatten
  .groupMapReduce(_._1)(_._2)(_ + _)
// Map("world" -> 2.2, "goodbye" -> 3.3, "hello" -> 5.5)
```

This:

- `flatten`s (concatenates) the maps as a sequence of tuples (`List(("hello", 1.1), ("world", 2.2), ("goodbye", 3.3), ("hello", 4.4))`), which keeps all key/values (even duplicate keys)
- `group`s elements based on their first tuple part (`_._1`) (group part of **group**MapReduce)
- `map`s grouped values to their second tuple part (`_._2`) (map part of group**Map**Reduce)
- `reduce`s mapped grouped values (`_+_`) by taking their sum (but it can be any `reduce: (T, T) => T` function) (reduce part of groupMap**Reduce**)

---

The `groupMapReduce` step can be seen as a [one-pass version](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.0-M5/src/library/scala/collection/Iterable.scala#L604) equivalent of:

```
list.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2).reduce(_ + _))
```

Answer (score 2):

Interesting, noodling around with this a bit, I got the following (on 2.7.5):

General Maps:

```
   def mergeMaps[A,B](collisionFunc: (B,B) => B)(listOfMaps: Seq[scala.collection.Map[A,B]]): Map[A, B] = {
    listOfMaps.foldLeft(Map[A, B]()) { (m, s) =>
      Map(
        s.projection.map { pair =>
        if (m contains pair._1)
          (pair._1, collisionFunc(m(pair._1), pair._2))
        else
          pair
      }.force.toList:_*)
    }
  }
```

But man, that is hideous with the projection and forcing and toList and whatnot.  Separate question: what's a better way to deal with that within the fold?

For mutable Maps, which is what I was dealing with in my code, and with a less general solution, I got this:

```
def mergeMaps[A,B](collisionFunc: (B,B) => B)(listOfMaps: List[mutable.Map[A,B]]): mutable.Map[A, B] = {
    listOfMaps.foldLeft(mutable.Map[A,B]()) {
      (m, s) =>
      for (k <- s.keys) {
        if (m contains k)
          m(k) = collisionFunc(m(k), s(k))
        else
          m(k) = s(k)
      }
      m
    }
  }
```

That seems a little bit cleaner, but will only work with mutable Maps as it's written.  Interestingly, I first tried the above (before I asked the question) using /: instead of foldLeft, but I was getting type errors.  I thought /: and foldLeft were basically equivalent, but the compiler kept complaining that I needed explicit types for (m, s).  What's up with that?

Comment: You don't need to use `force` here, because `toList` is strict.

Comment: As for `foldLeft` vs `/:`, you do realize the object and the first argument are swapped between them? The expression `x foldLeft y` is equivalent to `y /: x`. Beyond that, there's a bunch of syntax issues. Basically, you *have* to write `(y /: x) (folding expression)`, while `foldLeft` can be used as `x.foldLeft(y)(folding expression)`.

Comment: Yes, I knew about methods ending with : swapping the object with the argument.  That's how I wrote the example in the question.  I did forget to put y /: x in parens, though, and I bet that was a problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I reading this question quickly so I'm not sure if I'm missing something (like it has to work for 2.7.x or no scalaz):

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
val ms = List(Map("hello" -> 1.1, "world" -> 2.2), Map("goodbye" -> 3.3, "hello" -> 4.4))
ms.reduceLeft(_ |+| _)
// returns Map(goodbye -> 3.3, hello -> 5.5, world -> 2.2)
```

You can change the monoid definition for Double and get another way to accumulate the values, here getting the max:

```
implicit val dbsg: Semigroup[Double] = semigroup((a,b) => math.max(a,b))
ms.reduceLeft(_ |+| _)
// returns Map(goodbye -> 3.3, hello -> 4.4, world -> 2.2)
```

Comment: +1, although I'd write `ms.suml`, which is more concise and has the added advantage of not throwing a runtime exception on an empty list.

Comment: @TravisBrown, yes, so many convenient functions in scalaz; though `suml` may be scalaz 7 only? I only see `sumr` in 6.x.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a blog post about this , check it out :

http://www.nimrodstech.com/scala-map-merge/

basically using scalaz semi group you can achieve this pretty easily

would look something like :

```
  import scalaz.Scalaz._
  listOfMaps reduce(_ |+| _)
```

Comment: You can actually use `listOfMaps.suml`; it should do the same thing. from what I understand it means sumLeft, where it essentially runs `reduceLeft(_ |+| _)`

Answer (score 0):

a oneliner helper-func, whose usage reads almost as clean as using scalaz:

```
def mergeMaps[K,V](m1: Map[K,V], m2: Map[K,V])(f: (V,V) => V): Map[K,V] =
    (m1 -- m2.keySet) ++ (m2 -- m1.keySet) ++ (for (k <- m1.keySet & m2.keySet) yield { k -> f(m1(k), m2(k)) })

val ms = List(Map("hello" -> 1.1, "world" -> 2.2), Map("goodbye" -> 3.3, "hello" -> 4.4))
ms.reduceLeft(mergeMaps(_,_)(_ + _))
// returns Map(goodbye -> 3.3, hello -> 5.5, world -> 2.2)
```

for ultimate readability wrap it in an implicit custom type:

```
class MyMap[K,V](m1: Map[K,V]) {
    def merge(m2: Map[K,V])(f: (V,V) => V) =
    (m1 -- m2.keySet) ++ (m2 -- m1.keySet) ++ (for (k <- m1.keySet & m2.keySet) yield { k -> f(m1(k), m2(k)) })
}
implicit def toMyMap[K,V](m: Map[K,V]) = new MyMap(m)

val ms = List(Map("hello" -> 1.1, "world" -> 2.2), Map("goodbye" -> 3.3, "hello" -> 4.4))
ms reduceLeft { _.merge(_)(_ + _) }
```

Answer (score 0):

```scala
def mergeMap[A, B](ms: List[Map[A, B]])(f: (B, B) => B): Map[A, B] = {
  ms.flatten.foldLeft(Map[A, B]()) { case (acc, (k, v)) =>
    acc + (if (acc.contains(k)) k -> f(acc(k), v) else (k, v))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?