# How to merge a map of String to List functionally?

Tags: scala, collections, dictionary, functional-programming, generic-collections

I've built an abstraction such as this:

```
class Thing(val messages: Map[String, Seq[String]]) { 
  def and(that: Thing): Thing = {
    new Thing(this.messages ++ that.messages)
  }
}
```

`this`'s map of `String -> Seq[String]` needs to be merged with `that`'s map.

This is the best way I can think of to do this:

```
def and(that: Thing): Thing = {
  val keys = this.messages.keys ++ that.messages.keys
  val tuples = keys map {
    case key: String =>
      val theseMessages = this.messages.getOrElse(key, Seq[String]())
      val thoseMessages = that.messages.getOrElse(key, Seq[String]())
      (key, theseMessages ++ thoseMessages)
  }
  new Thing(tuples.toMap)
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262741/scala-how-to-merge-a-collection-of-maps). You can use the code provided in the accepted answerwith the combinator function being `{_ ++ _}`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a version that uses `groupBy`:

```
def and(that: Thing): Thing = {
  new Thing(
    (this.messages.toIndexedSeq ++ that.messages)
      .groupBy(_._1)
      .map { case (k,vs) => k -> vs.flatMap(_._2) }
      .toMap)
}
```

Comment: Not a bad answer, but maybe what I have is better? I think yours is harder to understand.

Answer (score 1):

The [Scalaz](http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/) library includes this function, the `|+|` (semigroup append) operator. Note that you will need to choose a more specific collection type than `Seq`, i.e. one that has a semigroup instance, so I've used `List`.

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

class Thing(val messages: Map[String, List[String]]) { 
  def and(that: Thing): Thing =
    new Thing(this.messages |+| that.messages)
}
```

You could also define a semigroup instance for `Thing`, and use the `|+|` operator to combine `Thing`s.

```
case class Thing(val messages: Map[String, List[String]])

implicit val ThingSemigroup = new Semigroup[Thing] {
  def append(t1: Thing, t2: => Thing) = new Thing(t1.messages |+| t2.messages)
}

Thing(Map("foo" -> List("bar"))) |+| Thing(Map("foo" -> List("baz")))
// Thing(Map(foo -> List(bar, baz)))
```

Comment: `implicit val ThingSemigroup = semigroup[Thing]((x, y) => Thing(x.messages |+| y.messages))` is more concise

Comment: I don't think that works in Scalaz 7, but `Semigroup.instance` looks like it does the same thing, thanks

Comment: Crafty, but I can't pull in Scalaz

Answer (score 0):

A more specific, slightly modified version of the answer I linked to in the comment which might make the approach a little clearer:

```
def and(that: Thing): Thing = {
  new Thing(this.messages.foldLeft(that.messages) { case (out, (keyToAdd, valuesToAdd)) =>
    out ++ Map(keyToAdd -> out.get(keyToAdd).map(_ ++ valuesToAdd).getOrElse(valuesToAdd))
  })
}
```

Also has the advantage of not looping over one of the maps.