# Scala: idiomatic way to merge list of maps with the greatest value of each key?

Tags: scala, scala-collections, reduce, scalaz

I have a List of Map[Int, Int], that all have the same keys (from 1 to 20) and I'd like to merge their contents into a single Map[Int, Int].

I've read [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262741/scala-how-to-merge-a-collection-of-maps) on stack overflow about merging maps that uses `|+|` from the scalaz library.

I've come up with the following solution, but it seems clunky to me.

```
val defaultMap = (2 to ceiling).map((_,0)).toMap
val factors: Map[Int, Int] = (2 to ceiling). map(primeFactors(_)).
        foldRight(defaultMap)(mergeMaps(_, _))

def mergeMaps(xm: Map[Int, Int], ym: Map[Int, Int]): Map[Int,Int] = {
    def iter(acc: Map[Int,Int], other: Map[Int,Int], i: Int): Map[Int,Int] = {
      if (other.isEmpty) acc
      else iter(acc - i + (i -> math.max(acc(i), other(i))), other - i, i + 1)
    }
    iter(xm, ym, 2)
  }

def primeFactors(number: Int): Map[Int, Int] = {
  def iter(factors: Map[Int,Int], rem: Int, i: Int): Map[Int,Int] = {
    if (i > number) factors
    else if (rem % i == 0) iter(factors - i + (i -> (factors(i)+1)), rem / i, i)
    else iter(factors, rem, i + 1)
  }
  iter((2 to ceiling).map((_,0)).toMap, number, 2)
}
```

Explanation: `val factors` creates a list of maps that each represent the prime factors for the numbers from 2-20; then these 18 maps are folded into a single map containing the greatest value for each key.

### UPDATE

Using the suggestion of @folone, I end up with the following code (a definite improvement over my original version, and I don't have to change the Maps to HashMaps):

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
import Tags._

/**
 * Smallest Multiple
 *
 * 2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers 
 * from 1 to 10 without any remainder. What is the smallest positive number 
 * that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?
 *
 * User: Alexandros Bantis
 * Date: 1/29/13
 * Time: 8:07 PM
 */
object Problem005 {

  def findSmallestMultiple(ceiling: Int): Int = {
    val factors = (2 to ceiling).map(primeFactors(_).mapValues(MaxVal)).reduce(_ |+| _)
    (1 /: factors.map(m => intPow(m._1, m._2)))(_ * _)
  }

  private def primeFactors(number: Int): Map[Int, Int] = {
    def iter(factors: Map[Int,Int], rem: Int, i: Int): Map[Int,Int] = {
      if (i > number) factors.filter(_._2 > 0).mapValues(MaxVal)
      else if (rem % i == 0) iter(factors - i + (i -> (factors(i)+1)), rem / i, i)
      else iter(factors, rem, i + 1)
    }
    iter((2 to number).map((_,0)).toMap, number, 2)
  }

  private def intPow(x: Int, y: Int): Int = {
    def iter(acc: Int, rem: Int): Int = {
      if (rem == 0) acc
      else iter(acc * x, rem -1)
    }
    if (y == 0) 1 else iter(1, y)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your tags suggest, you might be interested in a scalaz solution. Here goes:

```
> console
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info] 
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.0 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_15).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import scalaz._, Scalaz._, Tags._
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
import Tags._
```

There exists a Semigroup instance for Ints under a maximum operation:

```
scala> Semigroup[Int @@ MaxVal]
res0: scalaz.Semigroup[scalaz.@@[Int,scalaz.Tags.MaxVal]] = scalaz.Semigroup$$anon$9@15a9a9c6
```

Let's just use it:

```
scala> val m1 = Map(1 -> 2, 2 -> 3) mapValues MaxVal
m1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,scalaz.@@[Int,scalaz.Tags.MaxVal]] = Map(1 -> 2, 2 -> 3)

scala> val m2 = Map(1 -> 3, 4 -> 5) mapValues MaxVal
m2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,scalaz.@@[Int,scalaz.Tags.MaxVal]] = Map(1 -> 3, 4 -> 5)

scala> m1 |+| m2
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,scalaz.@@[Int,scalaz.Tags.MaxVal]] = Map(1 -> 3, 4 -> 5, 2 -> 3)
```

If you're interested in how this "tagging" (the `@@` thing) works, here's a good explanation: http://etorreborre.blogspot.de/2011/11/practical-uses-for-unboxed-tagged-types.html

Answer (score 6):

This solution does not work for general `Map`s, but if you are using `immutable.HashMap`s you may consider the [`merged` method](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.HashMap):

```
def merged[B1 >: B](that: HashMap[A, B1])(mergef: ((A, B1), (A, B1)) ⇒ (A, B1)): HashMap[A, B1]
```

> Creates a new map which is the merge of this and the argument hash
>   map.
>
> Uses the specified collision resolution function if two keys are the
>   same. The collision resolution function will always take the first
>   argument from this hash map and the second from that.
>
> The merged method is on average more performant than doing a traversal
>   and reconstructing a new immutable hash map from scratch, or ++.

Use case:

```
val m1 = immutable.HashMap[Int, Int](1 -> 2, 2 -> 3)
val m2 = immutable.HashMap[Int, Int](1 -> 3, 4 -> 5)
m1.merged(m2) {
  case ((k1, v1), (k2, v2)) => ((k1, math.max(v1, v2)))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, another solution only based on the standard library consists in merging the `Map`s as sequences before applying a [groupMapReduce](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/Seq.html#groupMapReduce[K,B](key:A=%3EK)(f:A=%3EB)(reduce:(B,B)=%3EB):scala.collection.immutable.Map[K,B]) which (as its name suggests) is an equivalent of a `groupBy` followed by a mapping and a reduce step on values:

```
// val map1 = Map(1 -> 2, 2 -> 3)
// val map2 = Map(1 -> 3, 4 -> 5)
(map1.toSeq ++ map2).groupMapReduce(_._1)(_._2)(_ max _)
// Map[Int,Int] = Map(2 -> 3, 4 -> 5, 1 -> 3)
```

This:

- concatenates the two maps as a sequence of tuples (`List((1,2), (2,3), (1,3), (4,5))`). For conciseness, `map2` is *implicitly* converted to `Seq` to adopt the type of `map1.toSeq` - but you could choose to make it explicit by using `map2.toSeq`.
- `group`s elements based on their first tuple part (group part of **group**MapReduce)
- `map`s grouped values to their second tuple part (map part of group**Map**Reduce)
- `reduce`s mapped values (`_ max _`) by taking their max (reduce part of groupMap**Reduce**)